# Angular http cache when two controllers run simultaneously

Tags: angularjs

In my web page I have two controllers, each making an http request **of the same URL**. The first controller takes fieldA from the response, and the second controller takes fieldB.

Given that the response is cached, will the second method invoked wait until the first one finishes and get the cache, or both http requests will be made because they are made simultaneously?

In controller 1:

```
        var msg = {};
        var promise = $http.get('/someUrl', msg, { cache: true } );
        promise.then(
            function(response) {
                fieldA = response.fieldA;
            }
        );
```

In controller 2:

```
        var msg = {};
        var promise = $http.get('/someUrl', msg, { cache: true } );
        promise.then(
            function(response) {
                fieldB = response.fieldB;
            }
        );
```

Comment: This sounds awkward.  It sounds like the 'page' doesn't have a main controller? Can you expand a bit?

Comment: The web page has several sections and each takes the same object from the application server. That object contains the user name and the date (t's the object cached in the browser that contains general login information). One section of the page displays the name, another section of the page displays the date. Each section has its controller.

Comment: You'd be better off having a single controller for the page, and then doing each part of the page as a directive, and feeding the data to each directive OR just have a single controller and reference all the parts of the page to that one controller.  Can you edit your question and put the relevant parts of your template/html file up, please?

In answer to your original question: it depends.  It depends on whether the first http call has completed as to whether the cache will be filled.  I suspect that they will all 'inflight' together which will be multiple calls to the backend.

Comment: use a service instead of duplicating the same request code ... but to answer question I believe 2 requests will be made. Easy to configure service so only one gets made though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a service that caches your promise

```
.service('ResponseService', function () {
   var promise; // Closure which is cache
   return {
     getPromise: function () {
       promise = promise || $http.get('/someUrl', msg, { cache: true } );
       return promise;
     }
   }
});
```

In your controllers, inject `ResponseService` and do `var promise = ResponseService.getPromise()`

Note that this is a simple caching mechanism. If you are planning to do more caching, take a look at [CachingFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache).

Comment: thanks, this worked, but can you explain the concept of caching promises?

Comment: The comment box is too small to explain everything about promise chaining, but I think this article will help you getting started: http://blog.xebia.com/2014/02/23/promises-and-design-patterns-in-angularjs/